# Database table Creation MySQL

Tags: mysql

I should create an online car rental system using MySQL and PHP, that allows customers to reserve a car by entering a search criteria such as Pickup date, Return data, car category etc.

- I have a **car** table that include the following columns: car_id, car_name, car_make, car_model.
- I have **reservation** table that include the following columns: reservation_id, reservation_date, customer_id, total_price.
- I have a **reservedCar** table that include the following columns: reservation_id, car_id, pickup_date, return_date

**Question** : I am required to add a column called quantity, as there are multiple cars with the exact same features. For example: if there are 5 Toyota cars and the customer wishes to reserve 2 of these cars, in the reservedCar table a two similar records should be inserted with two different car_id. How should it be done?

Comment: Are you asking how to add the column or how to reserve the car? Some code would be also helpful for a base understanding of how you did things.

Comment: you should add a column 'flag' in car table ,that can be boolen or smallint ,that will contain true/false value. whenever a user will reserve the car then table table particular row flag value will be update by true and on return date flag value will be false... and finally using the select count query you can display counts of numbered of reserved car

Comment: If you have database design questions on how to model you might want to look into Fully Communication Oriented Information Modeling (FCO-IM) is a method for building conceptual information models. Such models can then be automatically transformed into entity-relationship models (|ERM) with software https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCO-IM